# Laravel HTML Editor

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I have a form on my view like this

$emails is a list of file at my email template directory

```
{!! Form::select('name', $emails, null, ['id'=>'name','class' => 'form-control']) !!}
{!! Form::textarea('content', null, ['id'=>'content','class' => 'form-control']) !!}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $( "#name" ).change(function(){
        var name = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "{!! route('admin.email.getcontent') !!}",
            type: "GET",
            data: { name: name },
            success : function(result){
                $( "#content" ).val(result);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

so when i change the combobox value, the textarea value change to depend on which file i choose at combobox

the javascript run well, but what i see at my textarea is pure the content of the file with HTML tag like

```
<html>
    <body>
        aaaa this is body
    </body>
</html>
```

How to make my text area become a HTML editor which when i choose the combobox, only the result of HTML render show like

```
aaaa this is body
```

how to do it?

Comment: Kindly share a fiddle of the same. My earlier comments seems invalid in this context. Also let us know what is `result` ?

Comment: i need a html editor that didnt show the html tag, that i can edit it like microsoft word tools like bold, italic, etc. and with a javascript function that when i choose a dropdown, the html editor content change depend on what dropdown i choose

Comment: There are many plugins available to do this for you. Go for them..

Comment: @BharatGeleda yes i'm using CKEditor, but how to change the textarea content using ajax javascript?

Answer (score 1):

I used tinymce editor, it has a page that shows how to use it in laravel. I added it to Laravel 10 and it is working fine.

```
https://www.tiny.cloud/solutions/wysiwyg-laravel-rich-text-editor/
```

Or you can copy and paste this code into your document for testing purposes:

```
<script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/6/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
<script>
   tinymce.init({
     selector: 'textarea#content', // Replace this CSS selector to match the placeholder element for TinyMCE
     plugins: 'powerpaste advcode table lists checklist',
     toolbar: 'undo redo | blocks| bold italic | bullist numlist checklist | code | table'
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want it to be html instead of a string? try [htmlspecialchars_decode()](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars_decode)